# How to make Animations progress with user Slide

Tags: android, android-fragments, material-design, android-animation, android-transitions

I can see a lot of examples online on how to animate between two `Fragment`s using a `Button` click, but I can't find on how to tie an animation to a gesture motion.

I want my animation to progress with the sliding motion of the user, so my `View` will transform gradually as he slides. One example of this is the YouTube app, where the user can slide down the video, and the video will shrink to the bottom, while revealing the previous screen.

I also wonder if this can only be accomplished inside one `View` animation, or if this can be done in a Fragment Transition as well, with Shared Elements. This way we can transition between Fragment_1 to Fragment_2, using a sliding motion (and also triggered by a `Button` as well, such as in YouTube) and their respective `View`s will animate smoothly between one another.

Comment: https://github.com/dipanshukr/Viewpager-Transformation

Comment: That's not the kind of transformation that I am looking for

Comment: i dont think that you can use `Transition`s / `Scene`s for such "externally triggered" animations...

Comment: So what could/should I use? A CoordinatorLayout?

Comment: `CoordinatorLayout` is somehow closer as it is "animated" not by using an internal "timed animator" but rather by a scroll / fling made by a user

Comment: If you have any better ideas I am all ears.... I don't have any experience with android animation and I want to learn more